# Check for optional properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following interfaces

```
interface Foo {
  bar?: Bar;
}

interface Bar {
  baz?: Baz;
}

interface Baz {
  foobar: number;
}
```

I would assume that this is a safe way access data:

```
const test = (foo: Foo) => {
  const baz = (foo.bar || {}).baz || {};
  const foobar = baz.foobar;
};
```

However, it results in Error:(298, 26) TS2339: Property 'foobar' does not exist on type '{}'.

OK. But then I would not assume that this gives a different result:

```
const test = (foo: Foo) => {
  const baz = (foo.bar || {}).baz;
  const foobar = ({} || baz).foobar;
};
```

While this is a workaround, I'm not very happy with it, as I'm using baz a lot for more properties. To me this seems like a typescript bug.

Comment: if you look at this line `const baz = (foo.bar || {}).baz || {};`  you  will see two branches  which should be checked by TS. Because `baz ` property has type Baz but `{}`has type `{}` which  doesn't contain `foobar`

Comment: The first attempt sets the `baz` variable as `Baz | {}`. The second sets `baz` as `Baz | undefined`. Also, in the second attempt, you've reversed the order of `{}` and `baz` so it will always result in `{}`.

Comment: Your 2nd code chunk gives an error too: [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyARnFAPwBcyAQmQNwEC+BBoksiKdUOBRpAF5VacQY3wt8bcNHhJRgvoWQxMpKNRABXALbFoEqQnQgAzmGSQLyALzIAFGvTUM6AJR2AfMqInzlkJ2js4AdBrIAD6ROEzu4WJRMdhMEn6mNs4R9kKhWQzIAPSFyNBQ6FDMEgT+NtZgAEzBTpiumJ62PngqtYGJ9i3oCbzRsfFCaci9qupkzSlJJGLx+VD0RSVlFfxTGZarAIIA5nCgzUGjKSuzaxvIFsAANo+lUOWVktX40-UAzM3ONoeby+XYBJaCagABTIYGAcEeAB46IIfAMwhFLnEEkosetiqpgAAPHbTVbBXKrIwSIA). This isn't a TypeScript bug as far as I can tell. I don't see an actual question in your text so I'm not sure what answer you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear about your examples (they both seem to fail in quite similar ways). It doesn't matter too much though; right now, the best way to do the kind of nested optional property lookup you're trying to do here is something like this:

```js
const test = (foo: Foo) => {
  const foobar = foo.bar && foo.bar.baz && foo.bar.baz.foobar;
};
```

It'll work, but it's not pretty. There are a few libraries available to make this nicer though, e.g. [typesafe-get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typesafe-get):

```js
const test = (foo: Foo) => {
  const foobar = get(foo, 'bar', 'baz', 'foobar');
};
```

In the medium term though, the real solution is [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). This is a new JavaScript feature, which should be landing in TypeScript 3.7 this November. That'll look like this:

```js
const test = (foo: Foo) => {
  const foobar = foo?.bar?.baz?.foobar;
};
```

Comment: I can't wait for optional chaining! Best news in TypeScript for years!